# how do i take the results of my subqueries to join with another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, analytic-functions

. trying to link together the results from borrower,book, to AUTHOR.

desired results:

```
AUTHORID         AUTHORFIRSTNAME      AUTHORLASTNAME
1                     JIM                   SPARKS
2                     JAMES                 ALLEN
3                     MARCUS                RASHFORD
20                    PAUL                  POGBA
22                    THIERRY               HENRY
```

but am unsure how to link the returned, top authorids to retrieve the authorfirstname and lastname but i have not mentioned author table in the subquery

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make the question much more understandable.

Comment: What is the datatype of column `borrowdate`: is it a `date` or some kind of string?

Comment: borrowdate is formatted as a type of string - varchar2

Comment: @GordonLinoff cheers - i attempted to make my question more understandable. appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join those three tables along with `rank()` analytic function in the descending order for `count` within a subquery and then take less than equal to five in the main query :

```
SELECT authorid, authorfirstname, authorlastname
  FROM
  (
  SELECT a.authorid, a.authorfirstname, a.authorlastname, 
         rank() over (order by count(*) desc)  as rnk
    FROM AUTHOR a
    LEFT JOIN BOOK bk ON a.authorid = bk.authorid
    LEFT JOIN BORROWER br ON br.bookid = bk.bookid
   WHERE br.borrowdate between date'2017-01-01' and date'2017-12-31'
   GROUP BY a.authorid, a.authorfirstname, a.authorlastname
   )
  WHERE rnk <= 5
  ORDER BY rnk
```

If you're using DB version 12c+, it's easier to **fetch** them :

```
SELECT a.authorid, a.authorfirstname, a.authorlastname, 
       rank() over (order by count(*) desc)  as rnk
  FROM AUTHOR a
  LEFT JOIN BOOK bk ON a.authorid = bk.authorid
  LEFT JOIN BORROWER br ON br.bookid = bk.bookid
 WHERE br.borrowdate between date'2017-01-01' and date'2017-12-31'
 GROUP BY a.authorid, a.authorfirstname, a.authorlastname
 ORDER BY rnk 
 FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS WITH TIES
```

where I used `br.borrowdate between date'2017-01-01' and date'2017-12-31'` instead of `to_char(br.borrowdate) like '%2017'` to be able to benefit the index on the column `borrowdate` if exists any.

Those queries above return the rows with ties, e.g. they bring more rows than five provided that multiple rows match the value of 5th row.

**Do not** use `rownum` pseudocolumn for ranking purposes, since the value of it is calculated before ordering and might yield wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

So, if i get it correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
select authorid, authorfirstname, authorlastname 
 from 
  (select a.authorid, a.authorfirstname, a.authorlastname 
   from author a, borrower b, book c 
   where a.authorid = c.authorid and c.bookid = b.bookid
   and b.borrowdate like '%2017' 
    group by c.bookauthor 
    order by count(*) desc) xx 
 where rownum <=5
```

Comment: oh my goodness! yes! something like this but unsure how to format it in order to display results. this is so much neater than what i was thinking!  have been trying to mess around but perhaps still too bad at SQL. grrr. thanks for the help